# TypeScript: How to dynamically set properties on objects?

Tags: typescript

I want to convert a Typescript Map to an object. The following code shows a compiler error:

```
const sourceMap = new Map<string, string>();
sourceMap.set('foo', 'bar');

const jsonObject = {};
sourceMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    jsonObject[key] = value;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=30&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFcBOwCmBZAhgBxgXhjFQHcYtsAeaJASzAHMAaOKWhgPgAoBKAbgCh4yNOQB0EVFE4ByAGYgQ05tIBGmJNL79+oSLABW8MAHkV+1MFgEA3gF8BQlBhyj5SAKKZgAC06cAbpgANgiozADWqACe3PjsMNb8MMkwhuCm5pYA2pFRALr4MIEhqAK2WrrwQaiiQSD0nABSAMrGAHLirHT0NLJRnGkmZhZQ3HxAA)

The compiler doesn't like the line `jsonObject[key] = value;` saying:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.(7053)

How can I fix that or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an explicit type annotation to `jsonObject` to allow indexing with any string. The predefined type `Record` should work fine:

```
const sourceMap = new Map<string, string>();
sourceMap.set('foo', 'bar');

const jsonObject: Record<string, string> = {};
sourceMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    jsonObject[key] = value;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=8&ssc=41&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFcBOwCmBZAhgBxgXhjFQHcYtsAeaJASzAHMAaOKWhgPgAoBKAbgCh4yNOQB0EVFE4ByAGYgQ05tIBGmJNL79+oSLABW8MAHkV+1MCgAuGACULIJABMqrOkxZt67fDADeAL4CQigYOKLySACimMAAFpycAG6YADYIqMwA1qgAntz4Pn78MKUwhuCm5pYA2jm5ALq+KemoAgFauvCpqKKpIPScAFIAysYAcuJuDDSyuZwVJmYWUNx8QA)